# Windows10/powershell: how to count files and then sort them by subfolders?

Tags: powershell

I have a script in Linux that searches/counts all the files in subfolders and gives me a count for each.

Sample output when run: `my-count-script.sh /usr`

```
 5322 X11R6
  316 bin
   89 lib
 2165 libdata
   50 libexec
19220 local
   10 mdec
  206 sbin
 8970 share
```

This gives me count for all folders immediately inside `/usr`. So the actual path to share is `/usr/share`. path to bin is `/usr/bin`.

I guess `/usr` is the parent and the children includes `share`, `bin` and etc. I want the display to stop at the "children" level.

Any ideas how it can be done in power shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get child item count for each sub directory on its first level.

Gets all children that are directories then for each directory it gets all files recursively for each sub folder.

```
Get-childitem C:\Test -Recurse -Depth 0 -Directory | %{@{$_.Name = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File -Recurse).count}} | format-table
```

If you do not want the recursive count then run this which will just get you the file count in each sub directory

```
Get-childitem C:\Test -Recurse -Depth 0 -Directory | %{@{$_.Name = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File).count}} | format-table
```

Here is a function to also achieve what you would like

```
function Get-SubDirectoryCount(){
    Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
      [string]$Directory,
      [switch]$Recurse,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='FilesOnly')]
      [switch]$FilesOnly,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DirectoriesOnly')]
      [switch]$DirectoriesOnly,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='FilesDirectoriesOnly')]
      [switch]$FilesAndDirectories
    )
    Invoke-expression  "Get-childitem $Directory -Recurse -Depth 0 -Directory | %{@{`$_.Name = (Get-ChildItem `$_.FullName $(if($DirectoriesOnly){write-output "-Directory"})$(if($FilesOnly){write-output "-File"}) $(if($Recurse){write-output "-Recurse"})).count}} | format-table"
}

#Get Files and Directories Recursively 
Get-SubDirectoryCount -Directory C:\Test -FilesAndDirectories -Recurse
#Get Files Recursively 
Get-SubDirectoryCount -Directory C:\Test -FilesOnly -Recurse
#Get Directories Recursively
Get-SubDirectoryCount -Directory C:\Test -DirectoriesOnly -Recurse
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick one liner like this:

```
(ls c:\YourPath\*\* -File).Directory | Group-Object name
```

Comment: the listing didn't stop at the "children" level. it displayed all the subfolders and displayed the total number of files. there are 10 subfolders (children) on the parent folder and around 800+ subfolders in those 10 childen folders.

Comment: Amended my answer which I think gives you what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
Get-Childitem $home -recurse | Group-Object Directory -noelement
```

I have used $home as a directory spec here, but you will probably want to use one that's more relevant to your situation.

Comment: the listing didn't stop at the "children" level. it displayed all the subfolders and displayed the total number of files. there are 10 subfolders (children) on the parent folder and around 800+ subfolders in those 10 childen folders.